# ERROR: syntax error at or near "group" in SQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.3

Hello guys I am running this query to get some data from database table.

```
select pickup, supplier, sum(price)
from myrent_prices_to 
where (pickup BETWEEN '2018-01-01' and '2018-07-31')
and location SIMILAR TO '(%)' 
and vehicleclass SIMILAR TO '(%)'
and supplier SIMILAR TO '(%)' 
group by pickup, supplier
```

But it is giving me error below:

> org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.EngineException: Error happened
>   while running the report.     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.doRun(DatasetPreviewTask.java:135)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.runDataset(DatasetPreviewTask.java:97)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.DatasetPreviewTask.execute(DatasetPreviewTask.java:49)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.DataSetPreviewer.preview(DataSetPreviewer.java:69)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.birt.report.designer.data.ui.dataset.ResultSetPreviewPage$5.run(ResultSetPreviewPage.java:336)
>     at
>   org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:121)
>   Caused by: org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.odaconsumer.OdaDataException:
>   Cannot get the result set metadata.
>       org.eclipse.birt.report.data.oda.jdbc.JDBCException: SQL statement does not return a ResultSet object. SQL error #1:ERROR: syntax error
>   at or near "group"   Position: 236  ;
>       org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "group"   Position: 236     at

Comment: check postgres error log - it should be much more comprehensive

Comment: The statement looks fine to me. Maybe Birt is doing something to the query before it's actually executed